# How to set Global variable from other class method variable?

Tags: java, variables, global

I want to set value as global variable, that needs to access any class file.

Country.java:

```
public class Country {
    public String getMobileCode() throws SQLException, Exception{
       /* MySQL Conn part
        String cCode = rs.getString("COUNTRY_CODE");
       */
        if(cCode.equals("IN")){
            PHONE_NO_PREFIX = "91";
        }else{
            PHONE_NO_PREFIX = "33";
        }
        return PHONE_NO_PREFIX;
    }
}
```

Register.Java:

```
public class Register { 
    public static Country CountryBO = new Country();
    public static String PHONE_NO_PREFIX = CountryBO.getMobileCode();  // error: Unhandled exception type Exception

    public static String getPhone(String _message) {
         String Pattern = PHONE_NO_PREFIX;
   }
}
```

How can I access `PHONE_NO_PREFIX` in any class and define it as global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static initialization block, which will enable you to use try/catch blocks

```
...
public static String PHONE_NO_PREFIX;

static {
    try {
        PHONE_NO_PREFIX = CountryBO.getMobileCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Handle the exception here
    }
}
```

If `PHONE_NO_PREFIX` is to be made `final` (which is something you probably want to do), you can use a local static method:

```
public static final String PHONE_NO_PREFIX = getCountryCode();
private static String getCountryCode() {
    try {
        return CountryBO.getMobileCode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Handle the exception here
    }
}
```